# For Each doesn't work in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

Good afternoon,

I am working with these pivot table generated data, and I would like to fill some empty cells in the first columns (starting in N1) with the value above them:

(I wanted to post an image there but apparently I need 10 reputation to do it. How dumb is that?)

So I wrote this :

```
Sub orange_square()

Dim cellule5 As Range

For Each cellule5 In Range("N1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    cellule5.Value = cellule5.Offset(-1,0).Value

Next
End Sub
```

But it does nothing, so I wrote this:

```
Dim cellule5 As Range

For Each cellule5 In Range("N1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
     MsgBox (IsEmpty(cellules))
Next
```

Which gives me only one MsgBox with False. So I assumed it must for some reason have ran only for the first cell, hence I wrote the following as a test:

```
Dim cellule5 As Range

For Each cellule5 In Range("N1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
     cellule5.Value = 5
Next
```

and it replaced everything with 5. If someone understands any of that, their help will be fairly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: At first I thought it was because those data were in a table, but I unlisted it and the problem remains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking through columns,  1 column at a time. You need to use:

```
For Each cellule5 In Range("N1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Cells
```

Comment: Thank you ! I would have liked to Vote your answer up, but I need 15 reputation to do so.